# Problem with fopen and the windows console

Tags: c++, windows, console, fopen

I'm having a very strange problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7 x64. I have this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    fclose( fopen("hakuna", "w") );
    return 0;
}
```

It works very well when I compile it. When I go to the debug folder and double click on the exe it creates the file. But when I open the console and type in the destination of the exe and press "Enter" nothing happens. If there're some prinf-s they will appear, but the file is never created.
I'll be very grateful if someone is able to help me. I really have no idea why this's happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being created at your default directory - or wherever your cmdline active directory is.

For example, the cmdline will look like something like this.

```
C:\Users\Akari>
```

That's the directory where the file is being made.

Comment: Indeed, the default current directory for the Windows Shell (Explorer) is probably not the one where the executable is stored.

Comment: @user931392: After you type in the destination of the exe and press "Enter", type "dir" on the next line, and you'll see the file there.  Wherever "there" is.